# REGEXEXTRACT out of an XML Import in google sheets

Tags: xml, google-sheets, extract

I imported XML Data out of a script from a website into my google sheets and after some REGEXEXTRACT I now have the following rows:

+0",33.89,"4"],["Mar 31 2023 09: +0",**34.49**,"2"]]

+0",**4.3**,"10"]]

+0",6.003,"18"],["Mar 31 2023 09: +0",**6.231**,"25"]]

+0",**3.628**,"26"]]

+0",4.05,"1"],["Mar 31 2023 09: +0",**4.63**,"13"]]

I would like to extract the values that I already marked in bold, so the second to last numerical value out of every row. I tested a bit but can't seem to find something that does exactly what I want, because the rows that I extracted are different in length & composition due to the CONCATENATE function not structuring XML-input from every website the same. Is there a REGEXEXTRACT expression to do what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try:

```
=index(if(len(A:A),let(Σ,"\d+(?:\.\d+)?",regexextract(A:A,",("&Σ&"),"""&Σ&"""]]$")),))
```

[image]